# How to generate Month list in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `A` with `startdate` column which is `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` I need to write a query/function that generate a list of months from the `MIN` value of the column till `MAX` value of the column.

For example:

```
startdate
2014-12-08
2015-06-16
2015-02-17
```

will generate a list of: `(Dec-14,Jan-15,Feb-15,Mar-15,Apr-15,May-15,Jun-15)`

How do I do that? I never used PostgreSQL to generate data that wasn't there... it always has been finding the correct data in the DB... any ideas how to do that? Is it doable in a query?

Comment: Use generate_series(): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate sequences of data with the `generate_series()` function:

```
SELECT to_char(generate_series(min, max, '1 month'), 'Mon-YY') AS "Mon-YY"
FROM (
  SELECT date_trunc('month', min(startdate)) AS min, 
         date_trunc('month', max(startdate)) AS max
  FROM a) sub;
```

This generates a row for every month, in a pretty format. If you want to have it like a list, you can aggregate them all in an outer query:

```
SELECT string_agg("Mon-YY", ', ') AS "Mon-YY list"
FROM (
  -- Query above
) subsub;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8a2e/6/0)

Answer (score 5):

For people looking for an unformatted list of months:

```
select * from generate_series('2017-01-01', now(), '1 month')
```