# Monthly Counting PostgreSQL giving months

Tags: postgresql

I have a table for customers like this

```
cust_id | date_signed_up | location_id
-----------------------------------------
   1    |  2019/01/01    |      1
   2    |  2019/03/05    |      1
   3    |  2019/06/17    |      1
```

What I need is to have a monthly count but having the months even if its 0.  Ex:

```
monthly_count |  count
-------------------------
     Jan      |    1
     Feb      |    0
     Mar      |    1
     Apr      |    0
```

(months can be in numbers)

Right now I made this query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('MONTH', (date_signed_up::date)) AS monthly, count(customer_id) AS count FROM customer 
WHERE group_id = 1 
GROUP BY monthly
ORDER BY monthly asc
```

but it's giving me just for the months there's information, skipping the ones where it's zero. How can I get all the months even if they have or not information.

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of months.

[How to generate Month list in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448656/how-to-generate-month-list-in-postgresql)

```
  SELECT a.month , count( y.cust_id )
  FROM allMonths a
  LEFT JOIN yourTable y
    ON a.month = date_trunc('MONTH', (date_signed_up::date)) 
  GROUP BY a.month
```